# Length of monotonic subsequence in a permutation of [n]

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose I had a permutation of $[10]$. What length of a monotonic subsequence (increasing or decreasing) am I guaranteed to obtain?

My attempt: Although likely not the best method, I tried finding examples by inserting numbers to the sequence.

For $[3]$, least monotonic subsequence has length $2$: $(3,1,2)$

For $[4]$ least monotonic subsequence has length $2$: $(3,1,4,2)$

For $[5]$, least monotonic subsequence has length $3$: $(5,3,1,4,2)$

For $[6]$, is $3$: $(5,3,1,4,2,6)$

Hence I made the hypothesis that for each even permutations we get $\frac{n}{2}$ and for odd $\frac{n-1}{2}$. However, I found a counterexample for $[10]$ having a monotonic subsequence of length $4$: $(8,3,5,2,6,1,4,10,9,7)$

Is there any generalisation for permutations of $[n]$?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural first step might be to work this out for small $n$.

Comment: This is answered by the [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem)

Comment: And the formula is $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ (see [OEIS A003059](https://oeis.org/A003059)).